# MobileFirst Maximum value for accessTokenExpiration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Whats the MAX value for accessTokenExpiration in MobileFirst Hybrid application.

MobileFirst Server version: 7.1.0.00.20170330-0917. The default is 3600 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: AccessTokenExpiration shd be a valid Positive integer. I do not see any limit set on the expiration for 7.1 . for MFP8 however, there is a maxtokenexpiration property which will override this value and limit the actual token expiry time. refer here info on maxtokenexpiry https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_max_token_expiration_config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no max limit to the expiry. You can configure the value using the

[`<accessTokenExpiration>`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html) property in application-descriptor.xml